# why UNION ALL command in mysql doesn't give back any results?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to merge two queries into one, but UNION is not working for me.
Here is the code:

```
SELECT
Customer_A,
Activity,
Customer_P,
Purchase
FROM (
SELECT 
buyer_id as Customer_A,
COUNT(buyer_id) As Activity
FROM 
customer_info_mxs
GROUP BY buyer_id
UNION ALL
SELECT
buyer_id as Customer_P,
SUM(purchase_amount) As Purchase
FROM 
customer_info_mxs
GROUP BY buyer_id
)sub
```

I expect to have 4 columns as a result, but I get 2 instead (Customer_A) and(Activity).

Comment: A UNION query is probably inappropriate here. In your intended 4 column output, are `Customer_A` and `Customer_P` equal values? (are they intended to be the same buyer_id)

Comment: And welcome to SO - when posting a SQL question, it helps us if you can include a small sample of rows from the tables involved together with a sample of what you expect the query output to be from those rows.

Comment: Hey, Thank you for your response. 
Customer_A and Customer_p are not the same value although they are gonna have the same entities as buyer_id. they will be ordered by activity and purchase respectively.

Answer (score 0):

If the query is supposed to return a list of customers, their number of purchases, and the total amount they’ve spent, then you can use a single query like this:

```
SELECT mxs.buyer_id as Customer,
       COUNT(mxs.purchase_id) As Activity,
       SUM(mxs.purchase_amount) As Purchases
  FROM customer_info_mxs mxs
 GROUP BY mxs.buyer_id;
```

Otherwise, your first subquery will always be a `buyer_id` and a value of `1`.

Be sure to change `purchase_id` to whatever the unique `id` is for each purchase if you wish to see that number.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I didn't understand what you mean by the value of 1. Also, I have no clue about the 2nd part of your response, can you explain more?
I already came across the first solution that you provided by the way. My main goal is to creat a dataset in which returns 5 columns as:
Customer_A, Activity (top 100), customer_P, Purchase_P, inner join of activity and purchase

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some confusion about the union statement.  The union statement returns a row set that is the sum of all of the 'unioned' queries; since these queries have only 2 columns, the combined output only has two columns.  The fact that the columns have different names is irrelevant.  The column names in the output are being applied from the first query of the union.

One option is to just do

```
select buyer_id, count(buyer_id), sum(purchase_amount) from customer_info_mxs group by buyer_id
```

From your question, it looks like you are trying to do a pivot, turning some of the rows into additional columns.  That could be done with ... some difficulty.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I already came across the first solution that you provided by the way. My main goal is to creat a dataset in which returns 5 columns as: Customer_A, Activity (top 100), customer_P, Purchase(top 100), inner join of activity and purchase.
The reason that I have two customer culumns, is that I want to order by both activity and purchase and find out the inner join of them

Answer (score 0):

i read your comment,
'main goal is to creat a dataset in which returns 5 columns as: Customer_A, Activity (top 100), customer_P, Purchase(top 100), inner join of activity and purchase'

please try this query

```
SET @row_number = 0, @row_number2 = 0; 
SELECT t1.Customer_A,t1.Activity, t2.Customer_P, t2.Purchase
from (
      SELECT (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS n, t.Customer_a, t.Activity
      from (
            select buyer_id as Customer_A,COUNT(buyer_id) As Activity
            FROM customer_info_mxs
            GROUP BY buyer_id
            order by Activity desc
            Limit 100
            )t
      ) t1
left join (
      SELECT (@row_number2:=@row_number2 + 1) AS n, 
      FROM (
            select buyer_id as Customer_P, SUM(purchase_amount) Purchase
            FROM customer_info_mxs
            GROUP BY buyer_id
            order by Purchase desc
            Limit 100
            )t
      ) t2 on t2.n=t1.n
```

basic idea is, i just create some temporary number 0-99 to table 1 (t1) and join to temporary number on table 2 (t2)